# Can i connect my reactive app with Mysql database

Tags: react-native

I've searched all over the internet. I'm very new to reactnative and react. So i'm wondering how to connect my app with Mysql and perform CRUD operations.

Comment: Are you talking about a server connection, or just on device?

Comment: Server connection. I need to add, update, delete datas (on MYSQL WEB from my reactnative app.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to an on-board database, your best options are probably [Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-js), which as per their gitHub page is "faster than even raw SQLite on common operations, while maintaining an extremely rich feature set," [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage), or [react-native-local-mongodb](https://github.com/smartdemocracy/react-native-local-mongodb).

For off-device, what has worked for me--though it was a long road to get there--is using react-native-meteor ([at this repository)](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor) which does [CRUD operations with MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/). I used MySQL when I was working exclusively in Android, but Meteor and MongoDB is a nice marriage to RN for cross-platform deployment. Otherwise you can just use [Fetch](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html) in React Native, use a REST API server interaction that gives you a JSON response (which can use any server language you're comfortable with), and go from there. Good luck!

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I'd also like to mention that if you're using redux, there's a lot of good middleware for rehydrating the state

Comment: @klvs, you're so right about redux - it's just a road I've not gone down yet, but guess I'll need to at some point!

Comment: @kwishu You don't have to! It is really nice and worth looking at but sometime I feel like people are easily exaughsted by all these frameworks. Good suggestions! Plain old async storate would work too if it's not a lot of structured data.

Comment: Fetch API only fetches data's right ? It doesn't have capability to add, update or delete datas from database

Comment: You're right as far as I know, so that's why I've gone to react-native-meteor...someone can correct me on this if I'm wrong

Comment: @kwishnu can we use nodejs instead of Meteor?

Comment: @AVI , yes, the MEAN (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node.js) and MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, Node.js) stacks both use nodejs; I've never managed to query a mongodb with a simple Fetch or WebSocket request from a react native app, though I'm sure there must be a way